# Google Analytics and Android Applications

Tags: android, google-play

So yesterday my application update for rejected because of Violation of the Ad Policy.
I suspect it was that because I added a new function that, when my application loaded for the first time, it created a unique ID for that installation. I then sent that ID out with requests for data to my server, in order to track usage by device.
This morning I removed that code, submitted a new update and it was accepted.
I would like to track how often my application is being used by device every day, so I was looking at google analytics.

I managed to plumb it in, and it was working, but I need to know a few things first.

1. Do I need to have an opt out option?
2. Do I need to have a proper privacy policy?

Has anyone else implmented it into their apps?

Answer (score 1):

For that you have use Google Analytics.

You will get which device people use and also you can differentiate devices  , Android versions , countries  , regions etc.

It will very helpful for you to identify and strategic analysis of your application.

I would suggest Google Anlaytics is the best option and it will not violate the Google Play store policy.

Answer (score 1):

If you use google analytics to track anonymous stats, it's not necessary a privacy policy (you can add it anyway). Default stats are totally anonymous.

If you start tracking user specific information (and it seems you do), I think you definitively need to include one explaining what you're collecting and what for.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics is capable of tracking unique visitors without work on your end. Just do the standard page tracking, and unique users will come up under the audience section